# Error 1026 Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, flash-cs5

I'm trying to make a simple button with gotoAndStop command in AS3, but i keep getting error 1026. This is the code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

function onButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(10);
}
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
```

there are no other code except stop(); at frame 1

any help?

Comment: Error #1026 has to deal with constructor functions that are not named correctly, so some other code within your project is quite possibly triggering the error.

Comment: there are no other codes, the code above is all of it.

Comment: Well, I tested the code you posted with Flash CC 2014 and it compiles with 0 errors and executes properly. So there must be some other code that is triggering the error that you are not aware of.

Comment: You're right, I somehow put btn1 on document class. Stupid me. Thanks for the help!